# Find matching value in table, check if specific cell in same row is empty, find next if not

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a table which contains JIS numbers and I'm trying to match a JIS number with appropriate work orders from another table. The second table contains multiple work orders per JIS (all work orders have the JIS number on the same row). I've already written code to verify the number of JIS in each table and then add new rows so there should be a new row added to the processed table to match the work orders being pulled in from the raw table. What I want to do is:

For each JIS number listed in raw_tbl, match to a JIS number in processed_tbl.
If processed_tbl has an empty space in the corresponding Work Order column, fill in the values on that row with the ones from raw_tbl.
If the Work Order space has been used already, find the next instance of that JIS in processed_tbl and check again, repeat until an empty work order space is found.

I originally wrote this with application.match, not sure if this is appropriate or if I should switch to a .find method. I'm including the snippet I'm working with below, can add more if necessary but trying to keep the request uncluttered as I've tried several things and I'm sure I have some unused variables and/or commented lines throughout the rest of the code. I'd also rather not use offsets as these tables and/or the report they're created from may be rearranged occasionally. The code, as written, matches the JIS appropriately but overwrites the old data on the same line it originally matched with. Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
    For Each r In raw_tbl.ListColumns(raw_JIS_col_idx).DataBodyRange
                Set rangeFind = .Find(r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                
                If Not rangeFind Is Nothing Then 'JIS found in processed table
                    If rangeFind.Offset(0, 7).Value = "" Then 'check for empty work order
                        For lc = 1 To raw_tbl.ListColumns.Count
                            mc = Application.Match(raw_tbl.HeaderRowRange(, lc), processed_tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)
                                If Not IsError(mc) Then
                                    pRow = rangeFind.Row
                                    pCol = processed_tbl.ListColumns(mc).Index
                                    x = raw_tbl.DataBodyRange(rRow - 1, lc).Value
                                    processed_tbl.DataBodyRange(pRow - 1, pCol).Value = x
                                End If
                        Next lc
                    'else
                        'search for the next matching rangefind
                    End If
                End if
Next r
```

Comment: What does this `.Find(r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)` refer to i.e. `With what`? Do you have a column title or variable for `.Offset(0, 7)`? Will the 'match' with the empty cell (if any) always be the last (bottom-most) `JIS` occurrence?

Comment: This is encased in:

With processed_tbl.ListColumns(processed_JIS_col_idx).DataBodyRange

I do have a column title, "Work Order #: Work Order Number"

No, the match will not always be on the bottom row. The first half of the code counts the JIS occurrence in raw_tbl and processed_tbl, then compares the two counts and adds that many rows by copying the row from processed_table. Then the next part of the code (from my original post) executes.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)